# What should follow "I'll tell you another reason..."?

Tags: sentence-construction, conjunctions

Is any of these the correct form of the sentence?

"I'll tell you another reason *I will not participate"

"I'll tell you another reason *why* I will not participate"

"I'll tell you another reason *for which* I will not participate"

If not, what is it? What's the grammar behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*why* and *for which* both make sense, however. *For which* sounds more formal, and looking at the context of the sentence, this is probably what you want to be going for.

Comment: I'm not convinced *for which* makes sense here.  Reasons provide an answer to the question "why?"  They don't give an answer to the question "Which one?"